# Tag Disambiguation - [cdk], [ncurses-cdk], [aws-cdk]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonym-process, tag-disambiguation

The current [cdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cdk) tag is aliased to [ncurses-cdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ncurses-cdk).

[aws-cdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-cdk) already exists.

The acronym of CDK has been used by multiple projects, but [AWS Cloud Development Kit](https://aws.amazon.com/cdk/) is a major toolkit on the AWS ecosystem that is gaining adoption.

Assuming CDK means [Curse's Development Kit](https://invisible-island.net/cdk/manpage/cdk.3.html) is no longer appropriate, as this is a unix library.

There are already a growing number of questions referring to AWS CDK that are incorrectly tagging them with [cdk], adding to the confusion.

Comment: I'm also seeing: https://material.angular.io/cdk/

Comment: I can buy that. Synonyms changed

Comment: @Machavity I would burn/block list cdk instead

Comment: @DanielA.White The tag was already a synonym in this case. And getting tag blocks is complicated, since we need a CM or Dev to edit the blocklist. A synonym here hurts nothing, and should hopefully guide people to use the right tag

Comment: @Machavity sure but what about the angular case? the previous ncurses case?

Comment: I'm not following the logic in "Assuming CDK means Curse's Development Kit is no longer appropriate, as this is a unix library." Do people not use UNIX any more? Am I the only one left?

Comment: @miken32 the issue is it's no longer the only meaning for CDK, simply the oldest. A lot of questions related to AWS or Angular contexts are getting tagged ambiguously as a result. if we block the `cdk` tag then people can start tagging more specifically, rather than assuming `cdk` means angular or aws, which are the most common questions today.

Answer (score 1):

I think Machavity made a mistake here.

I propose we keep [aws-cdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-cdk), [angular-cdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-cdk) and [ncurses-cdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ncurses-cdk) and burn/block [cdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cdk). that way there's no ambiguity and forces the OPs to choose the right `cdk`.

Comment: If you would, post this as a separate question. Blocklists have to be done by staff, and we'll need an appropriately tagged questions for that if we do it.

Comment: @Machavity is it safe to assume someone can go ahead and create the `aws-cdk` and `angular-cdk` tags so they're available? Last I checked the only two tags were `ncurses-cdk` and the `cdk` alias for the same. I dont have the rep on the main community, or I'd add a tag myself to some of the questions to get it going.

Comment: @Stephan they already exist.

Comment: @DanielA.White oof im misremembering why I opened this. The point was about the alias causing people to ambiguously tag questions, less so about availability of the alternatives. Sorry for the confusion. Did you already open the burn/block on the alias?

Comment: @Stephan I havent

Comment: Stephan's subsequent MSO post: [Burn/Block Tag - \[cdk\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423235/1478931)